# When browser is resized, is the whole page and the linked css files re-rendered by the browser?

Tags: html, css, browser

For example, consider the following case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <style>
@media (min-width: 500px){
body {
    background-color: red;
}
}
@media (max-width: 499px){
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
}
</head>
<body>
    Hi there!
</body>
</html>
```

After loading the page, if we were to change the width of the browser, after the width is less than 500px, the background of the page will change.

**Question:**

Does browser re-renders the whole page and the linked css files whenever we resize the browser ? If not, how is this dynamics structure preserved ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What "dynamic structure"? The CSS rules are always loaded and are just waiting to be applied as an when conditions are met.

Comment: @Paulie_D But to determine whether the conditions are met, someone has to check those condition that whether they are met or not.

Comment: @Paulie_D Is this what the browser doing ? Checking the condition when it is resized ?

Comment: @Paulie_D or is it checking those conditions all the time ?

Comment: That's what the browser does. One rule no longer applies but another does, a repaint occurs, It checks on each "stop".

Comment: @Paulie_D "stop" ?

Comment: Every time the re-sizing stops...if you don't move the mouse,,,that's a stop.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok, thanks